# Conditional Check Issue || Is Entry in any of these Categories?

Tags: categories, conditionals, phpstringfun

**Scenario**

The issue is that entries are in several categories and can be Featured (a FieldPack pill with yes/no options) but only want certain categories to show the entry.

So I have a `featured_listing_category` `WB Category fieldtype` setup.

I had this worked out but apparently still not working the way expected. I have the following code:

`{if !'{exp:phpstringfun function="strpos" par1="{featured_listing_category}"}{segment_4_category_id}{/exp:phpstringfun}’}`

With `{featured_listing_category}` outputting `399|400` and `{segment_4_category_id}` outputting `372`

I'm trying to test whether `{segment_4_category_id}` is included with `{featured_listing_category}`.

If it helps here is my template snippet:

```
{exp:channel:entries
      channel="listing"
      dynamic="no"
      {if segment_5 ==''} category="{segment_2_category_id}&{segment_4_category_id}"{/if}
      {if segment_5} category="{segment_6_category_id}&{segment_4_category_id}"{/if}
      orderby="level_sort"
      sort="asc"
      search:featured_listing="yes"
      disable="categories|pagination|category_fields|member_data"
    }
{if !'{exp:phpstringfun function="strpos" par1="{segment_4_category_id}"}{featured_listing_category}{/exp:phpstringfun}'}
    <div class="listingItem featuredListing">
      <div class="featuredIcon"></div><!-- /.featuredIcon -->
      <div class="image">
        {if main_image}
        {exp:ce_img:pair src="{main_image}" width="165" height="165" allow_scale_larger="yes" crop="yes|center|center" }<a href="/listing/details/{url_title}"><img src="{made}" width="{w}" height="{h}" alt="" /></a>{/exp:ce_img:pair}
        {/if}
        {if main_image ==''}
        <img src="/uploads/default_listingItemImage.jpg" alt="" />
        {/if}
      </div><!-- /.image -->
      <div class="content">
        <div class="buttonReviews">
          <p><a href="/listing/details/{url_title}/{segment_2}/{segment_4}" class="btn orange">View Listing</a></p>
          <div class="reviews">
            {exp:rating:stats collection="Book Reviews" entry_id="{entry_id}" precision="1"}
              <p>{stars_overall_avg}</p>
              {if rating_no_results}<p><a href="/listing/details/{url_title}/">Rate This Listing</a></p>{/if}
            {/exp:rating:stats}
          </div><!-- /.reviews -->
        </div><!-- /.buttonReviews -->
        <h3><a href="/listing/details/{url_title}">{title}</a></h3>
        {addresses limit="3"}
        <p>{if company_name}{company_name}<br />{/if}{if address1}{address1}{/if} {address2} {if city}<br>{city}, {/if} {if state}{state}{/if} {if phone}<br>Phone: {phone}{/if} {if website_url}<br> <a href="http://{website_url}" target="_blank">{website_url}</a>{/if}</p>
        {if row_count == total_rows && total_rows > 1}
        <p><a href="/listing/details/{url_title}/">See More</a></p>
        {/if}
        {/addresses}
        {if overview}
        <h4>Overview</h4>
        {overview}
        {/if}
      </div><!-- /.content -->
      <div class="clearfix"></div><!-- /.clearfix -->
    </div><!-- /.listingItem -->
    {/if}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{if "|{featured_listing_category}|" *= "|{segment_4_category_id}|"}
    {!-- Is Included --}
{if:else}
    {!-- Isn't Included --}
{/if}
```

Outputs as example:

```
{if "|399|400|" contains "|372|"}
```

Pipes required either side to ensure partial cats don't get incorrectly matched, e.g. 399 contains 39.

Comment: Using `{if "|{featured_listing_category}|" *= "|{segment_4_category_id}|"}
testing
{/if}` inside my `exp:channel:entries` gets me a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in` error.

Comment: Same error with `{if "|399|400|" *= "|400|"}
testing
{/if}` too :\\

Comment: Issue is with `*=` never used that before w/EE. Is that available w/2.7.3?

Comment: looks like `=*` is only a 2.9 thing :///

Comment: upgrading EE, will let you know if that works after that!